# Magento2 How to Get Newsletter Subscribed Collection into phtml file

Tags: magento2, php, collection, newsletter, data

I used Magento 2.2.4 Version.

Magento2 How to Get Newsletter Subscribed Collection into phtml file

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended way:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subscriberCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\Collection');

foreach($subscriberCollection as $subscriber):
   print_r($subscriber->getData());
endforeach;
```

Recommended way:

```
protected $subscriberCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollectiona
) {
    $this->subscriberCollection = $subscriberCollection;
}

public function getSubscriberCollection() {
    $subscriberCollection =$this->subscriberCollection->create();
    return $subscriberCollection;
}
```

In phtml:

```
$subscriberCollection = $block->getSubscriberCollection();
foreach($subscriberCollection as $subscriber):
    print_r($subscriber->getData());
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$newsletterCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $newsletterCollectionFactory->create();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());
}
```